# Adding timeline for answers in the API

Tags: feature-request, api, timeline

I've noticed that there is [now a way](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline) to fetch a timeline for a particular question. Is there a reason why this isn't available for answers as well?

I'd like to create a userscript which would require pulling from both questions and answers, and was wondering why this wasn't implemented. Seems like an oversight, or an intentional design.

Here's my plan:  I'd like to add a userscript to add the ability to "watch" certain questions/answers. For example, if I find a post that's NAA, I can add it to a watch list, and ensure that it gets deleted. If it get's edited in the review queue, and doesn't add anything of substance, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13421702), and pops back out, I could view a list and see all the posts that met this criteria (Mostly, for reflagging). Right now, I'm unable to get the timeline for answers, so this is hindering my ability to continue, without using screen scraping.

Comment: Well, answer timeline expose more things, e.g. accepts, maybe they don't want to expose this just yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Isn't the accept time already exposed when you hover over the check mark?

Comment: Any chance I could get an official response? I'm curious why this was only created for questions, and not answers as well.

Comment: That part's easy. There wasn't a separate timeline for answers when that API route was created. I don't know when this would be added, but I can't think of a reason it shouldn't be